# Dell H310 RAID controller in PowerEdge 2950 III

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, sas

Is anyone able to confirm whether the Dell H310 RAID controller will happily live in a PowerEdge 2950 III?

It's a PCI Express 2.0 8x card. I see reports of the H700 in the 2950, which is the same type of card, but no direct reports of the H310.

Comment: Why do you not simply ask Dell-support? They will give you that type of information even if there is no valid support contract any more. Have the express-service-number ready for your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have both H310 and H700 raid controllers install on two different PowerEdge 2950 III servers and I never encountered any issues with them.

Comment: Awesome! Any issues with cables with the H310? Can you remember what brand you bought? I have come across reports of difficulties with different brands.

Comment: I will let you know on Sunday when I'm at work.

Comment: Any luck finding out that information?

Comment: Yes, Dell PN: R9PXF Optical Bay kit

Comment: Optical bay kit? Not quite what I expected - does the kit contain the two required SFF8087 to SFF-8484 cables?

Comment: Yes, my supplier sells them as one, the optical bay kit + SFF8087 cables